# Should I use (select count(id) from table2) as col1, or should I store a counter on table 1 and increase it on inserts?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, count

My page seems to be slow, I have a page which has at least 20 "select count" queries, every row has has at least two fields making a count subquery. I though it wouldn't be that slow, now I am unsure. I want to know which one is the default method for situations like this. (if I need to index some columns, I want to decide which column, too, but the count function counts ids from some table so i don't think it's an inexing problem either."

```
if(isset($_GET["me"])) $me="and post.memberid=".$_SESSION["memberid"]; else $me="";
$votecount="(select count(voteid) from vote where vote.postid=post.postid) as cv";
$commentcount="(select count(commentid) from comment where comment.postid=post.postid) as cc";
$countagree="(select count(voteid) from vote where vote=1 and vote.postid=post.postid) as ca";
$ismyvote=sprintf("(select vote from vote where memberid=%s and vote.postid=post.postid) as mvote",$_SESSION["memberid"]);
$plq=sprintf("select *, %s,%s,%s,%s from post where post.dateposted>=NOW() - INTERVAL %s day %s",$votecount,$commentcount,$countagree,$ismyvote,$since,$me);
```

WHen I started developing this, I thought mysql would cache the counts of the primary key fields and It wouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Can you put your query here? Usually the join operation are the most expensive ones, so if you are doing count over joins, your bottleneck is on the join. Count has complexity O(n), so it would not be that bad.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE is faster for MyISAM tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try both Vik's query and also danihp's counter column approach.  Time and compare the results - based on your actual data and application.

I do believe however that the real answer that will help you the most is to really learn and use explain plan (if you don't already)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explain_Plan.

You mentioned "seemed to be slow" and "I though it wouldn't be that slow, now I am unsure." and "so i don't think it's an indexing problem either."

So it seems like making changes would be very trial and error unless you are really measuring the results of your changes and explain plan will help with that and with indexes and a lot more.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are making 3 separate queries over vote, and 2 other queries over comment and post, and also using subqueries... This is bad.

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
select
  post.*, 
  count(vote.voteid), 
  count(comment.commentid) 
from 
  vote, post, comment
where
  vote.postid=post.postid and
  comment.postid=post.postid and
  vote=1 and vote.postid=post.postid and
  memberid=$_SESSION["memberid"] and vote.postid=post.postid and
  post.dateposted>=NOW() - INTERVAL %s day and post.memberid=".$_SESSION["memberid"]"
```

It probably does not work and you will need to fix some things, but this way will allow the dbms to do some query plan optimizations for you, and it will probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

A select count may lock all table. You can use a counter on another table. But the best solution is use autoincrement field type.